# Beginner question about making a program change based on user input

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn to code and decided to give myself a simple task. It's a madlib game (roses are..., ... is blue, etc..). I want to make the program change '... is blue' to '... are blue' based on use input. So if the use inputs 'my head' the program says 'my head is blue' instead of 'my head are blue.'

I've tried to implement this:

```
if thing in ['my','your']:
    print(thing + " is blue")

else:
    print (thing + " are blue")
```

However the programme only reads 'are' when 'my' or 'your' are written on their own. Is there a way to print something based on whether or not a word is present, not if a certain phrase or word is written?

```
colour = input ("roses are... ")

thing = input(" ... are blue")

love = input("I love ... ")

print("roses are " + colour)

if thing in ['my','your']:
    print(thing + " is blue")

else:
    print (thing + " are blue")

print("I love " + love)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you bee looking for whether the user inputs a plural vs. a singular noun?

Comment: You reversed the left and right sides of `x in y`. You need `'my' in thing or 'your' in thing`. What you wrote means `thing == 'my' or thing == 'your'`.

Comment: `any(word in thing for word in ['my', 'your'])` is most likely what you actually want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a sub-string is in your list by doing:

`if any(word in thing for word in ['my', 'your'])`

pretty self explanatory:

it's a for loop that just returns true or false. it basically looks at your variable `thing` which is storing a string, checks if it's also within your list

So full code:

```
colour = input ("roses are... ")
thing = input(" ... are blue ")
love = input("I love ... ")


print("roses are " + colour)

if any(word in thing for word in ['my', 'your']):
    print(thing + " is blue")
else:
    print (thing + " are blue")

print("I love " + love)
```

Comment: Yes that works! Could you possibly explain how 'if any(word in thing for word in ['my', 'your']):' works?